Will carbonara still have the same flavor/texture with Parmesan instead of Pecorino Romano?
I am planning on making a mushroom & bacon carbonara but, I only have parmesan. Will it be a good substitute for Pecorino Romano?

Pecorino Romano is a sheep's milk cheese. Parmesan is a cow's milk cheese.  They do have a different flavor profiles, but behave similarly.  Parmesan will do just fine. In fact, both can be used in carbonara, and sometimes they are even used in the dish together.
